# Question about OptionalHeader->SizeOfImage in PE format

Tags: reverse-engineering, portable-executable

Good afternoon!

PE file image size in virtual memory = 0x26000 bytes:
[x64dbg->MemoryCard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrZ0U.png)

OptionalHeader->SizeOfImage = 0x20000 bytes:
[PE-bear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqQKb.png)

Question: Why is the size of the PE image in memory different from the size in SizeOfImage(0x26000 != 0x20000)?

Comment: Are you sure you counted that 0x26000 correct?

Comment: No, I'm a sleepy chump! SizeOfImage = 0x20000 corresponds to the size of the PE image in virtual memory, I just counted in decimal not hex. I apologize for the stupidity. Topic closed.